# how to configure master branch in GitHub to accept pull request from a specific branch only

Tags: github, pull-request, restriction

I need to configure GitHub protection rule for master branch which supports to raise pull request from a specific branch (ex: develop -> master) only. If any user tries to raise pull request from any other branch to master that should not be allowed.

Is above requirement possible, if yes how to configure.

I searched GitHub documents, repository settings and lot of blogs. But couldn't found any thing.

Thanks,
Raghunath.

Update 8-Apr-2020:
It seems there is no feature to implement above requirement (received confirmation from GitHub community admin)

Comment: If you have an answer to the question, it's perhaps better to write an answer below rather than edit the question.

Comment: It is not an answer, so I have edited rather than posting as answer